# Why numpy.random.choice and numpy.full() does not exit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pycharm

I am a newbe in python programming. I am running Python 2.7 on Mavericks and I have installed numpy, scipy and matplotlib. 
I have:
scipy.version=0.11.0
numpy.version=1.6.2
I try to run this code on PyCharm but I get these error .

```
import numpy  ;
import scipy;
import matplotlib;
import sys,os
from numpy import *;
from scipy import *;
import random;

numpy.random.choice(20,10) #AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choice'

numpy.full((3,3),7)   #AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'full'
```

Comment: You import `numpy` as `np`, but you use `numpy.full` and `numpy.random.choice`.  You can use `np.full` and `random.choice`.

Comment: Given your imports `np.full` and `full(...)` should work.  But drop the `*` imports.

Comment: These are some very strange error messages to see from the code you've shown. I'd expect a NameError when you try to use `numpy`. It doesn't seem like you've shown all the relevant code.

Comment: @zondo your suggestin is not logic and it does not work

Comment: @hpaulj, Why I have t drop the * ? you suggestion does not work.

Comment: @user2357112, I edited my code and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Jeanne: Yes, you are right.  Use `random.choice((20, 10))` rather than `random.choice(20, 10)`.  `np.full` should work, though.

Comment: Did you call a file `numpy.py`?

Comment: @zondo, No. see this Manual    http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: @user2357112, No, I import the librairy numpy

Comment: @user2357112, it seems that I dont have the right version of numpy.

Comment: @Jeanne: Okay.  (I'm sorry, I don't use numpy).  You should still use `np.random.choice`, not `numpy.random.choice`.  I agree with user2357112, though: if that is all of your code, you should be getting a `NameError`, not an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the numpy release notes, `np.full` isn't added until [numpy 1.8.0](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/release.html#numpy-1-8-0-release-notes) -- You seem to be using 1.6.2.  If you search in that document, `numpy.random.choice` looks like it was a highlight in `1.7.0`, so again, you're a bit too out of date. . .

As the current seems to be at least 1.10.1 -- maybe it's time for an update?

Comment: How can I update. I have tried    sudo pip install --upgrade numpy but I get an  error   The directory '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: did you try the `-H` flag as it is suggesting?  Beyond that, it looks like permissions issues on your machine.  I'm not generally super great at that sort of sys-admin level stuff, so I might not be of much help :-/

Answer (score 2):

If these functions are missing from your version of `numpy` there are good alternatives:

```
In [408]: np.random.choice(20,10)
Out[408]: array([17,  5,  2, 16,  9,  1,  6, 18,  2,  8])
In [409]: np.random.randint(0,20,size=10)
Out[409]: array([ 8,  8,  1, 19, 18, 10, 15,  9, 13, 17])

In [413]: np.full((3,3),7)
Out[413]: 
array([[ 7.,  7.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  7.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  7.,  7.]])
In [414]: np.ones((3,3))*7
Out[414]: 
array([[ 7.,  7.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  7.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  7.,  7.]])
In [415]: x=np.ones((3,3));x[:]=7;x
Out[415]: 
array([[ 7.,  7.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  7.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  7.,  7.]])
```